# R shiny read specific csv file based on conditional input using reactive

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I'm trying to create a **shiny** app that takes a **csv** file and extracts specific information from it. When I load one file and run my code is alright. But now I want the User to be able to choose which CSV file to analyze, because each one contains different books. Here is the code I have so far

```
library("shiny")
library("tidyverse")
library("stringr")

## Define UI
ui <- fluidPage( 

    titlePanel("Find words in the text"),

  ## Sidebar panel
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(

             ## Textual input
            selectInput("source", "Choose Text",
                         choices = c("Book 1" = 1,
                                     "Book 2" = 2),
                         selected = "Book 1"),

            textInput("word", "Insert words", value = ""),

            helpText("Type the word or words (separated by comma)\n
                  that you would like to find"),
            submitButton(text = "Search", icon("refresh")),
            br(), 

            textOutput("text")
        ),

        ## Main panel for outputs
        mainPanel(            
            tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("Main",
                         tableOutput("view")),
                tabPanel("Summary",
                         tableOutput("summary"))
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    k <- reactive({
             k <- ifelse(input$source == 1,
                              read_delim("book1.csv", delim = ";"),
                              read_delim("book2.csv", delim = ";"))
    })

    output$view <- renderTable({
        k %>%
            filter(str_detect(text,
                              str_split(input$word, ",")[[1]]))
    })

    output$text <- renderText({
        palabras <- str_split(input$word, ",")[[1]]
        n.times <- select(k, text) %>%
            str_count(c(palabras))
        paste("The word ", c(palabras),
              " appeared: ", n.times, " times")
    })


    output$summary <- renderTable({
        p <- str_replace_all(input$word, ",", "|")
        k %>%
            extract(col = text,
                    into = "Keyword",
                    regex = str_c("(",p, ")"),
                    remove = T, convert = T) %>%
            na.omit()
    })
}

## Create Shiny app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I also tried to change the part that begins with `k <- reactive({` (where `k` is the tibble where I want to have my book) for something where I first load each book and then I just send it to `k`, like this

```
book1 <- read_delim("book1.csv", delim = ";")
book2 <- read_delim("book2.csv", delim = ";")

k <- reactive ({
         k <- ifelse(input$source == 1,
                     book1,
                     nook2)
              })
```

I've being trying for couple of days using tutorials and stackoverflow, but I can't find what really fits me. I tried several different ways but apparently I'm doing something wrong with the `reactive` function. I would be very thankful if somebody could help me to solve it and Explain my mistake, as this is my first Shiny app.

*Just for the record*: If I remove everything related with the `reactive` part and only load the file into `k` with something like `k <- read_delim("book1.csv", delim = ";")` then my app works perfectly for the word counting.

Comment: Don't use `ifelse`, it is both not fit for this and has bad properties; just use `k <- reactive({req(input$source); if (input$source==1) book1 else book2; })`. Then always refer to your data as `k()` (yes, it is now a "function").

Comment: Thank you so much, indeed it does the work. I tried before using `if` instead of `ifelse` bu without the `k()`, and when I used `k()` I did using `ifelse`. Do you perhaps know why ifelse is not fit for this?

Comment: For one `ifelse` is meant for vectors, not singletons. Two, it tends to alter the return values' class, see `ifelse(T, Sys.time(), Sys.time())`. Glad it worked!