# How can I use modify a dataset within an output in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm new to Shiny and trying to create an app that displays two interactive before and after Sankey diagrams based on user input. The user input is used to pick a specific excel sheet, and then the excel sheet is modified using make_long. Since the user input guides what data sheet is used, I'm doing all of this within a renderPlot function. The code works outside of this function, but when it's put in and the app is run nothing is output.

I've tried running the entire code (choosing data and outputting plot) in renderPlot with essentially this code. I know the data is being run properly because I've used view() throughout.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggsankey)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(tidyr)
library(ggalluvial)


server <- function(input, output, session){
output$Sankey <- renderPlot({
if(input$x & input$y) 
bef <- read_excel("data1.xlsx")
else bef <- read_excel("data2.xlsx")

bef.l <- bef %>% make_long(col1, col2, value = col3)

ggplot(data = bef.l, 
aes(x = x, 
next_x = next_x
node = node, 
next_node = next_node)+
geom_alluvial(mapping = NULL, 
data = bef.l.o, 
position = "identity"
)
})
}
ui <- fluidPage(
plotOutput("Sankey")
)
```

I've also tried using reactive before so I can feed the data to both the before and after outputs, but I get this error: "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

```
datatable <- reactive({
if (x & y & z) 
bef <- read_excel("data1.xslx")
else bef <- read_excel("data2.xlsx")
return(bef)
})
```

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58740179/16421247) might be helpful. Try wrapping the entire `if...else` statement in `reactive` and assign that to an object. i.e. `df <- reactive({
  if(input$x & input$y) read_excel("data1.xlsx")
  else read_excel("data2.xlsx")
})`. Do this assignment outside your `renderPlot` function.

Comment: Also, your `ui` does not have any inputs. Where are `input$x` and `input$y` coming from?

Comment: @nightstand I accidentally left that off UI when making this post; the inputs are there in the code I'm working with. When I use the `df <- reactive({ })` code outside the renderPlot function, I get errors in the renderPlot code, I assume because it's been set to a function and not the data. I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here.

Comment: What is the error message you get? Also for debugging purposes, you can try displaying the data with `tableOutput`.

Comment: When I use `tableOutout` to check, I get this error: cannot coerce class ‘c("reactiveExpr", "reactive", "function")’ to a data.frame. The error I get for the plot is "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" (with the first function being `bef[is.na(bef)] = 0`.

Comment: When you call the data frame, try adding `()` after the object name. Like my example below: `output$table <- renderTable({df()})`

Comment: That still doesn't solve the problem. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Sure! I also suspect that your problem could be from `make_long`. When you call `make_long` on the imported data, each data frame might have different structure/columns, and you would have to modify the arguements in `make_long` accordingly. But I can't be sure about this without seeing your data. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read in your data using `reactive()` and assign that to an object. Within the `reactive` use `if...else` to specify the dataset you're reading in. When you reference your data frame, add `()` after the object name. i.e. `df()`.

If you want to modify your data, you can do so in `reactive` as well. Using `ggsankey::make_long` in the way described in this example worked for me.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggsankey)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset", # replace this with your inputs
              choices = c("iris", "mtcars")),
  plotOutput("my_plot")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  df <- reactive({
    if(input$dataset == "iris") {
      dat <- iris # replace this with your data
      dat |> make_long(Sepal.Length, Species)
    } 
    else {
      dat <- mtcars # replace this with your data
      dat |> make_long(gear, cyl)
    } 
  })
  
  output$my_plot <- renderPlot({
    df() |>
      ggplot(aes(x = x, next_x = next_x,
                 node = node, next_node = next_node,
                 fill = factor(node), label=node)) +
      geom_sankey()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: After some fiddling around with this and adjusting for what I needed, this worked! Thanks again for your help :)